# shinyFiles not working with modules

Tags: r, shiny

I'm developing a rather large shiny app and used the methods from [this talk on shinydevcon](https://github.com/rstudio/ShinyDeveloperConference/tree/master/Modules) to modularize it.
Now I was trying to use the package `shinyFiles` to get a "Save as" type dialog:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

# Dummy module for MCVE
saveModule <- function(input, output, session) {
    # Taken straight from shinyFilesExample()
    volumes <- getVolumes()
    shinyFileSave(input, NS("test")("save"), roots = volumes, session = session)
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    callModule(saveModule, "test")
}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    # Taken straight from shinyFilesExample()
    shinySaveButton(NS("test")("save"), 'Save file', 'Save file as...', filetype=list(text='txt', picture=c('jpeg', 'jpg'))))
)

runGadget(app = ui, server = server, viewer = dialogViewer(title = "test"))
```

This doesn't work correctly when trying to navigate folders or switch roots.
When pulling the code out of the `callModule`, it does work, but as I said, the actual use case has a rather large app and I don't want to clutter the `app.R` with code from a single module.

Is there any way to get `shinyFiles` to work correctly in a `callModule` context? Or some other viable work-around?

For reference, here is a working `server`:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    volumes <- getVolumes()
    shinyFileSave(input, NS("test")("save"), roots = volumes, session = session)
}
```

with `ui` and `runGadget` as above.

Comment: Don't you need to make separate UI and server elements of a module? It looks like the server part is modularized, but the UI isn't.

Comment: @Carl I do this in the app, but it is irrelevant to the problem - it's still there if I add the shinySaveButtton via a function, so I've omited that for brevity.